# Adding WEB-INF/lib to build path

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

When I create a new java EE project in Eclipse,will the WEB-INF/lib folder be automatically added to the java build path or do I need to  add it manually to the build path from the project properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have WTP (Web Tools Platform) installed in your Eclipse, it'll be added automaticaly when your project is created as an web project.

Answer (score 1):

will be automatically added :yea: